# How do I return filtering meta data in a REST API search query

Tags: api, rest

I'm currently designing and implementing a RESTful API in PHP. 
The API allows users to search for hotels.

A simplified example of the search request is:

```
GET hotels/searchresults?location=<location>     #collection of hotels within location
```

The response also contains some meta information about the returned collection.
The basic structure of the response is:

```
“meta": {
     “totalNrOfHotels": 100,
     "totalNrAvailable": 80
},
“hotels": [
     {
     “id": 123,
     “name": "Hotel A"
     },
     {
     “id": 135,
     “name": "Hotel B"
     },

     ...
]
```

This resource also supports pagination:

```
GET hotels/searchresults?location=<location>&offset=0&limit=20
```

Now, there are a few filters that can be applied to the search results, e.g. stars, rating score.
For example, if I want just 2 star hotels, I can query:

```
GET hotels/searchresults?location=<location>&offset=0&limit=20&stars=2
```

Now, in the user interface for filtering, it is common to display the number of options available per filter setting:

[image: Stars filter]

In my opinion, these numbers can be seen as meta data about the search query. So, we could add an extra field to the meta in the response:

```
“meta": {
     “totalNrOfHotels": 100,
     "totalNrAvailable": 80
     “filterNrs": {
          "stars”: {
               “1": 1,
               “2”: 9,
               “3”: 39,
               “4”: 12,
               “5”: 11,
               “none”: 9
          }
     }
},
“hotels": [
     {“id": 123,
     “name": "Hotel A"
     },
     {“id": 135,
     “name": "Hotel B"
     },

     ...
]
```

So, I have two questions:

1. Should this “filterNrs” property sit in the meta section, as proposed above? To me, it doesn’t make sense to be a separate resource/request
2. How can we deal with the fact that this can slow down the query? I’d prefer to make the “filterNrs” field **optional**. We are thinking of using a “metaFields" parameter to allow the user to specify which fields in the meta she would like to recieve. We already support this for the hotels returned, with a “fields” parameter. (Similar to: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_partial). Alternatively, we put this field filterNrs (or the full meta info) in a separate resource, something like `hotels/searchresults/meta`. From a developers perspective would you prefer to have this split into multiple resources or have a single resource with the option to show full or partial meta information?

Answer (score 0):

Does the number rated per star count varies? For example, do I get different "filterNrs" for the queries below?

```
GET hotels/searchresults?location=1
GET hotels/searchresults?location=2
```

I would expect such filters to be contextual, so different locations would return different numbers per star count, which indicates this is some form of contextual information related to the query.

Otherwise if the results are global this indicates it's a separate resource. If it's a separate resource scenario, you can use links to access the numbers and other details about it:

```
“meta": {
     “totalNrOfHotels": 100,
     "totalNrAvailable": 80
     “filterNrs": {
          "stars”: {
               "options" : ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "none"],
               "details" : "http://example.com/stars"
          }
     }
},
```